# How can I reset the mouse axes when respawning a player?

Tags: unity, c#, camera, input, character-controller

I am making a simple parkour game in which the camera will follow the mouse based on the mouse input axis * the sensitivity. This works great, but when I want to reset my character to the start I cant figure out how to reset the mouse axis to zero, thus preventing me from resetting the camera rotation. I have tried `Input.ResetInputAxes();`, but that seems to only reset the buttons.

```
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController characterController;
    public Transform Player, camera;
    public Camera cam;
    public float XSensitivity, YSensitivity;
    public bool grounded, jumping;
    public float forwardSpeed, horizontalSpeed, jumpPower, gravity, sprintModifier;

    [HideInInspector] public float sideSpeed, lastPlayerPosX, lastPlayerPosZ, jumpSpeed, verticalRotation, horizontalRotation;

    private float isSprinting = 1;

    void Update()
    {
        //This is where I get the axes
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        //This is how I rotate the player and camera 
        verticalRotation += -mouseY * YSensitivity;
        Player.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, horizontalRotation, 0);
        horizontalRotation += mouseX * XSensitivity;
        cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(verticalRotation, horizontalRotation, 0);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }

        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), forward = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        grounded = characterController.isGrounded;

        if (grounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey("left shift"))
            {
                isSprinting = sprintModifier;
            }
            if (Input.GetKey("left shift") == false)
            {
                isSprinting = 1f;
            }
            jumping = false;
            jumpSpeed = 0;
            sideSpeed = .75f;
        }
        else
            jumpSpeed -= (gravity * 25) * Time.deltaTime;

        if (Input.GetKey("space"))
        {
            sideSpeed = .25f;
        }
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Jump") != 0 && !jumping)
        {
            jumping = true;
            jumpSpeed = jumpPower;
        }

        lastPlayerPosX = Player.transform.position.x;

        lastPlayerPosZ = Player.transform.position.z;

        Vector3 motion = new Vector3(horizontal * horizontalSpeed * sideSpeed, jumpSpeed, forward * forwardSpeed * isSprinting);
        characterController.Move((Player.transform.rotation * motion) * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "deathbarrier")
        {
            //Resets player to starting position
            Player.transform.position = new Vector3(20.5f, -2, -22.5f);
            //Is supposed to reset all inputs (including mouse)
            Input.ResetInputAxes();
            //Sets camera rotation to 0, but only for one frame before the stored mouse axes change it
            camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reset the mouse axes.

The mouse axes (e.g. `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")`) reflect mouse movement over the last frame. If you do not move the mouse, the value returned from this axis will be 0.

You need to reset your fields `horizontalRotation` and `verticalRotation` in your `OnTriggerEnter()`.